# Adding values from WPF TextBox to List

Tags: c#, wpf

My goal is to add newly created Student's parameters from TextBox to List collection.
As far as I understand, the code below does not do so.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        btnCreateStudent.Click += btnCreateStudent_Click;
    }

    private void btnCreateStudent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Student student = new Student();
        student.Name = txtFirstName.Text;
        student.Surname = txtLastName.Text;
        student.City = txtCity.Text;

        student.Students.Add(student);
        txtFirstName.Text = "";
        txtLastName.Text = "";
        txtCity.Text = "";
    }

    class Student
    {
        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }
        private string surname;

        public string Surname
        {
            get { return surname; }
            set { surname = value; }
        }
        private string city;

        public string City
        {
            get { return city; }
            set { city = value; }
        }

        public List<Student> Students = new List<Student>();
    }
}
```

Comment: A `List`, or a `ListBox`?

Comment: A List. I need it to store data input made by a user of the Form in order to later use it to display in TextBox when user presses buttons "Prevoius" and "Next" in the Form.

Answer (score 2):

Have you bound the `List<Student> Students` with the ListBox in frontend. Use Data Binding in WPF. That way as soon as you update data, UI is updated automatically.

Here's the code. In XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="StudentTemplate">

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>

 </DataTemplate>



<ListBox Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StudentTemplate}"/>
```

Here is a tutorial on it:

http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine to add it into a list. Of course if you want to add the list into a listbox you can easily do it by doing something like this:

Make a ListBox tag in your XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="studentList"/>
```

Than in your codebehind:

```
studentList.Items.Add(student);
```

In fact you wouldn't need no List at all just initializing the student objects and fill them in.